# Deleting nodes via neo4j_client library doesn't work

Tags: c++, libneo4j-client

I am working on an Ubuntu application, which shall create and delete nodes depending on the local file system content.

I am initializing the connection using

```
_pSession = neo4j_connect(oss.str().c_str(), NULL, NEO4J_INSECURE);
```

running the query

```
Match (n) WHERE id(n) = 193 detach delete n
```

doesn't fail, but also doesn't delete the node.

neo4j_update_counts returns:

```
nodes_created 0 nodes_deleted 0 relationships_created 0 relationships_deleted 0 labels_added 0 labels_removed 0
```

Running the same command in the browser deletes the node. I can also read and create nodes in this session, why can't I delete nodes?
Is there a configuration / initialization issue?

Thanks a lot for support!

Answer (score 0):

Found my onw mistake!
There query I build with ostringstream. The stream content I did convert to neo4js run statement parameter (const char*) by calling query.str().c_str() 
This is not a valid call, as the resulting string will be be uninitialized.
Bottomline: the query was broken!